# Specific solar circuit setup recommendation?

Tags: circuit-design, dc-motor, solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

For a setup which uses:

a 100Ah 12V battery (Absorbed gel mat Lead acid), with an MPPT solar charge controller,

a 12V 12-55A DC electric motor as the primary load,

additionally some 12V LED lights and electronics,

and a solar panel array of about 1kW STC-rated power as a kind of a target, to cover for losses of operation at NOCT, to have (on average) more than 350W power input from the panels on a sunny day;

—— what kind of cell number / voltages should the panels have to organize this circuit?

is it possible that the charge controller has a way to directly feed the motors when they operate, to keep the battery without load at most times in a (sunny) day?

Thank you very much

Comment: I can comment later if others don't. Ask. || See http://www.gaisma.com for useful data on your site. The kWh/m^2/day is effective sunshine hours by month.

Comment: What is motor duty cycle / Wh load during a worst case day?

Comment: You need the battery to act as a voltage source and the solar panels as a current source with a Voc about 25% above Vbat (max) unless MPPT is specified otherwise. Choose worst case solar outage with battery capacity to prevent lack of supply.

Comment: I am not sure what the duty cycle represents so I googled and, I believe it could be described as a duty type S8 (continuous operation periodic duty with related load speed). It is a marine propeller which the motor turns. And, the Wh load depends on many factors of operation but, more or less the minimal current for operation is 12A, and therefore the 144W per motor (there are two) are kind of a target for the minimal desired power input of the panels, 144x2 (40W or so for LED lights and electronics) would be around 350W therefore a 400W power input should be present for a few hours daily

Comment: Therefore if the total STC rated power of panels is 1000W, at NOCT it should be 800W at midday, and then with less sunshine in the morning or afternoon a 400W could be achieved, I guess?

Comment: Also, can you please explain what is Voc 25% above Vbat

Comment: @ivanantuns  Voc = Vopen-circuit = unloaded panel voltage in full sun. Vbat = battery voltage. So Voc = Voc  25% = open circuit voltage = battery voltage x 1.25.

Comment: 400 W x 2 hours = 800 Watt hours = 800 Wh. | To supply load without battery discharge you need >= 400W from the panels. With a 1000 W panel this will ON AVERAGE be easily achieved on an AVERAGE winter day in most areas. Where is this located?  The battery will "fill in for cloudy periods et but should usually not be deeply discharged. Battery = 12V x 100 Ah = 1200 Wh nominal capacity. On a very cloudy/dark/sunless day the 800 Wh load would use 2/3 of full battery capacity. Even a deep discharge rated battery should not be this deeply discharged very often for decent lifetime.

Comment: A 12V 100 Ah battery will often do well enough in this application. 200 Ah will last more than twice as long due to much less % discharge on low sun days.

Comment: Thanks, so it means I need panels with a 15V output, or, an output which is reduced to 15V by a charge controller. But does voltage vary with sunshine radiance variation (W/m2), or is it only the current which goes up/down? Or both? (Sorry if off topic). Regarding sunlight, the area in question has a very high amount of sunshine, averaging 2700 hours per year (about 220-230 days of clear sun), and the latitude is 43N

Comment: @ivanantuns Nominal 12V panels are usually rated at 18 Vmp (Volts max power) (36 cells) allowing room for lead acid boost voltage plus some headroom.  || PV panels are close to insolation dependant constant current sources with Vmp remaining relatively constant across the load range. Open circuit V (Voc) is typically about 125% of Vmp. Imp (I max power ) is at Vmp. Isc (I short circuit) is usually <= 110% of Imp (where of course Vsc = 0). For practical purposes a 12V nominal panel will make more than enough voltage to make its light level controlled current in normal light ranges.